# Excel vlookup formula not working on second page

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am using this formula on a single sheet and it works perfectly:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A$3:$A$24,Team2_Score!$A$1:$C$150,3,FALSE)=0,"#N/A",VLOOKUP($A$3:$A$24,Team2_Score!$A$1:$C$150,3,FALSE))
```

I need to also use it on 3 other sheets, but it is not working on the new sheet.

Comment: Please provide some more info. Are you simply copy-pasting this exact formula to another sheet? Or using a similar formula but with cell references changed? What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: The formula was copied from the original page and references changed to match desired results, now I get N/A on the new page for the results

Comment: Here is a link to the file   http://www.mynsna.org/Blauv/AssocScore.xlsm

Comment: if you look at Team 1 the formula's will work for the entire week, when I try to make team 2 the formula doesn't work. I am still new and know it is something stupid, just don't know what

Comment: Simply `=VLOOKUP(A3,Team1_Score!$A$1:$C$150,3,FALSE)` may do all that you need and make copying the formula around easier.

Comment: OK, Thank's but I still need if the cell is 0 to read N/A. Do I place the trim in the VBA?

Comment: I have some redoing to do, but I am using a macro to copy and paste the data to Team2_Score how would I trim the result?

Comment: how would i record a macro so that it trim's in the process of copy and paste?